# When Adding a Second Screen to my Android Application It Wont Open

Tags: android, mobile

I've been working on an android application and it has always contained only 1 screen, I've decided to add a menu screen to my application to develop it further, but once I added the menu screen and tried to run it, it crashed upon opening.

This is my MainMenu.java file:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainMenu extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
    }

}
```

This is my 'mainmenu.xml' file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="453dp"
        android:maxHeight="150dp"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/guitarlogo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally my AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.finalyearproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- Splash Screen Activity / Launcher -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.finalyearproject.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.finalyearproject.TunerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If I keep only the top activity and put that as "com.finalyearproject.TunerActivity", that opens fine. It's only when I try to add the 2nd screen/activity that it crashes. It could be something I've missing, but I've looked everywhere for assistance!

LogCat:

```
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.finalyearproject/com.finalyearproject.MainMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at com.finalyearproject.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:12)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    ... 11 more
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    ... 24 more
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
03-26 15:59:28.974: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    ... 27 more
```

Comment: How are you switching in between these activities? Can you post that code please?

Comment: Crashes how? Where is the logcat?

Comment: Added the LogCat file, The app just comes up "Stopped Working" with an OK button to dismiss the error @Kaediil

Comment: And @ksudu94 I havn't got the onClick set up to switch between the two just yet because I can't get the first screen to show yet was going to set it up first then work on implementing the code

Comment: Whatever the image is you are putting in the Image Button is too big, see the OutOfMemory error?

Comment: @Kaediil I would have never thought of that! Still on a steep learning curve! Thanks bud, appreciate it! How do I give you positive feedback for that?

Comment: I just reposted my answer. You can vote it and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception in the logcat is a bit hard to decipher, but often on Android when there are a cluster of exceptions, the bottom one is the root cause of the problem.  this log cat shows an OutOfMemory exception loading the image, which tells you that the image yoiu are placing on the button is too big.